# Create a log of what's being sent by email in my script

Tags: bash, shell, awk, centos

This script currently monitors a log file for keywords. Upon discovery of said keywords, the script then produces a message pertaining to the state of a server (up or down). It then outputs an email directly to me. The rest of the script just kills the script after a predetermined period of time.

Finally, what I'd like to do now is send the same info being sent to email, to a log file: emailoutput > /var/log/server_mon.txt

I've tried to use the cat and exec command to direct the printed messages to a file, but my syntax is wrong every time. Not really a programmer and not sure how or where exactly to apply the command. my guess is somewhere after "print" but again, not sure how.

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

tail -fn0 /var/log/user | /usr/bin/awk '
    /disconnect_tcp_conn/ { report("down") }
    /daemon apps started/  { report("up") }

    function report(curr_state,    msg) {
        if ( prev_state != curr_state ) {
            msg = "Server is " curr_state
            system("mail -s \047" msg "\047 mail@gmail.com </dev/null")
            print msg | "cat>&2"
            prev_state = curr_state
        }
    }
'

 &
PID=$!

DIEAT=`expr $SECONDS + 58`
while [ -d /proc/$PID ] && [ "$SECONDS" -lt "$DIEAT" ]
do
        sleep 1
done

[ -d /proc/$PID ] && kill "$PID"
wait
```

Expected result is to have whats being output to email, to a text file for the purpose of keeping track of how often the script is reporting the servers condition.

I'm running this script on centos 5.5 btw..

Comment: `print msg | "cat>&2"` is printing the message to stderr. Do you want to print it to `/var/log/server_mon.txt` **instead of** stderr or **in addition to** stderr?

Comment: instead.. but in addition too wouldn't be bad either since the majority of the time this script will be ran as a cron job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print msg | "cat>&2"` is printing the message to stderr. Do you want to print it to `/var/log/server_mon.txt` **instead of** stderr or **in addition to** stderr?

There's a lot of options including:

```
awk '
    ...
    print msg | "cat>&2"
    print msg > "/var/log/server_mon.txt"
    ...
'
```

Remove `print msg | "cat>&2"` if you no longer need it.

or to get both with one `print`:

```
awk '
    ...
    print msg | "tee -a \047/var/log/server_mon.txt\047 >&2"
    ...
'
```

or:

```
awk '
    ...
    print msg
    ...
' | tee -a '/var/log/server_mon.txt' >&2
```

or:

```
awk '
    ...
    print msg | "cat>&2"
    ...
' 2> >(tee -a '/var/log/server_mon.txt' >&2)
```

So many options....

Comment: Can a time stamp be added to each entry relatively simple?

Comment: With GNU awk yes, with other awks not so much. Post a new question.

Comment: Just posted a new question for the timestamp, however, i just realized that the output of the log file is reporting the opposite state then the email notification with the email notification being the correct state (server up/down).. any ideas as to why? I replaced:  print msg | "cat>&2" with:  print msg | "tee -a \047/var/log/server_mon.txt\047 >&2".   I can make a new post about this as well but i thought it might be relevant to the current post.

Comment: my mistake. I mispoke

Answer (score 1):

In your awk script make sure msg makes it to stdout:

```
print msg
```

Then outside your awk script add:

```
| tee -a /var/log/server_mon.txt
```

Comment: Ok will try that tomorrow

Comment: this also works and i see that the tee command allows for both log and screen to get the message. ty